# The buttons of back and forward of the WKWebView do not activate when they are suppose to canGoForward/Back

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I am trying to implement a social media option in an App, where you can go directly to the twitter page of a company.

The WKWebView works fine, but once I should be able of going back or forward pressing the buttons, these buttons do not activate.

Is there any code I did not implemented?

In case is useful to see the interface.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7vw0.png)

```
class twViewController: UIViewController,WKNavigationDelegate {
var theUrl:URL? = nil
@IBOutlet weak var twWeb: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    twWeb.navigationDelegate = self
    theUrl = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/EsAsturiasTV")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: theUrl!)
    twWeb.load(myRequest)
}
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    if (twWeb.canGoBack){
        twWeb.goBack()
    }
}
@IBAction func forward(_ sender: Any) {
    if (twWeb.canGoForward){
        twWeb.goForward
    }
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    backButton.isEnabled = twWeb.canGoBack
    forwardButton.isEnabled = twWeb.canGoForward
}
```

While debugging I saw that the webView function is called so it suppose to enable the buttons, but it does not.

What makes it even more weird is that I implemented the exact same code for Facebook (just changing the url) and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Back and Forward button status of the WkWebView can also be retrieved using Property observers. Please find the relevant code below. It is in Obj-C. hope you can convert it to Swift.

```
- (void)addAllObservers
{
    [_wkWebView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoBack" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [_wkWebView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoForward" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

- (void)removeAllObservers
{
    [_wkWebView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoBack"];
    [_wkWebView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoForward"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"canGoBack"] && object == _wkWebView) {

        // handle property change: get the value of _wkWebView.canGoBack
    }
    else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"canGoForward"] && object == _wkWebView) {
        // handle property change: get the value of _wkWebView.canGoForward
    }
}
```

`_wkWebview` is the instance of `WkWebview`. You can add `addAllObservers` in WkWebview creation place. So, When property observers are in place, whenever the "`canGoBack`" and "`canGoForward`" property value is changed, callback will be received in "`observeValueForKeyPath`" method where Button status can be enabled / disabled based on the current value.

Hope it helps.